# Rewriting the URI when accessing the site through a subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have a domain bar.org and its subdomain foo.bar.org. Behind these two domains runs a Django website, accessible via gunicorn.

The config of bar.org is classic and is the following :

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  bar.org;
client_max_body_size 4G;

root   /home/bar/dev/bar/;

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;

}
}
```

My issue concerns the subdomain foo.bar.org. I want every request to foo.bar.org/XXX to be rewritten to /foo/XXX of my Django website, and the same from foo.bar.org/foo/XXX to /foo/XXX. I tried some URL rewriting commands but it didn't work. Has anyone already made a similar nginx configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible implementation is:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name foo.bar.org;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /foo$request_uri last;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        ...
    }
}
```

The `foo.bar.org` server block should proxy requests to `/foo` transparently. Notice we remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` directive to prevent the URI being rewritten.

The `location /` block ensures that URIs which do not begin `/foo` are rewritten.

Comment: I would use `location /foo/` cause otherwise `GET /footest` will not be rewritten to `/foo/footest`